# UWP AppBarButton MenuFlyout remove top margin

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a `MenuFlyout` which is spawned from an `AppBarButton`. The flyout has a top margin of 4 which I used to remove like this:

```
<MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
    <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-4,0,0"/>
    </Style>
</MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
```

However, this does not work anymore after I upgraded Target Version from 1803 to 1809.

How can I remove the margin again? Please see my code and a picture of the problem below. The flyout spawns from the button with the ellipsis icon.

```
<AppBarButton Style="{StaticResource AppBarMoreButtonStyle}" Name="Menu" Width="{StaticResource TopBarHeight}" Icon="More">
    <AppBarButton.Flyout>
        <MenuFlyout>
            <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Name="Switch" Click="Switch_OnClick" Text="Item" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="{StaticResource ButtonLogoutContent}" Click="AppBarButtonSignOut_OnClick" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </AppBarButton.Flyout>
</AppBarButton>
```

[image: MenuFlyout]

Edit: Result of Xeorge Xeorge's suggestion. Starting point of the Flyout:

[image: MenuFlyout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void AppbarButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            YourFly.ShowAt(AppbarButton, new Point(AppbarButton.ActualWidth-160, AppbarButton.ActualWidth-10));
        }
```

You must put the flyout inside the  instead
node, with x:Name instead of Name.

```
   <MenuFlyout x:Name="YourFly"  >
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item"  x:Name="item1"  Width="160"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Log out" x:Name="item2" Width="160"/> 
        </MenuFlyout >
```

as an extension of your question, you should put on a fixed width on your flyout items.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. When use `ShowAt` and specify the point, it align the MenuFlyout's left top corner with the AppBarButton's left top corner. And as I cannot know the width of the MenuFlyout, I can't get the placement right.

Comment: the vertical margin is totally gone for me, especially after the small update, i do not know what you mean with the width

Comment: I updated OP with an image of trying your suggestion. What I mean is that the Flyout expands from the red dot. To get the Flyout to fit inside the window, I need to know its width, which I only can by explicitly defining it myself.

Comment: Thank you. I tried putting Min and Max width on the MenuFlyout itself instead, and it gave the correct result.